# What aspects of a board game might be patentable?

Tags: patentability

I have invented a board game, and I'm investigating the route of patenting some parts of it.

Are there any board games that are already patented? What parts or mechanics might be patentable? For example, could gameplay be patented? Anything about the design of the board, or how players interact with it?

Comment: Related: [Can game mechanics be patented?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/210/can-game-mechanics-be-patented)

Comment: You should look into design patents for the specific items used along with copyright and trademark.

Comment: check out: http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/17458/game-patentability

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the delete answer button. After revising, my previous answer seems to be mistaken. There is an online article at ipwatchdogs about board games and the US patent system apparently differs from the EU's on this. There (eu), games (but not the apparatus (e.g. board)) are unpatentable per epc art. 52.

For the US please refer to the question in the comments or goigle for the article I mentioned.

Comment: Would you be able to show some references for this, as that would make your answer exceedingly useful for posterity? Especially since your answer contradicts the accepted answer on [can game mechanics be patented](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/210/can-game-mechanics-be-patented).